# iOS - UI design in coding and not in XIB or Storyboard is Feasible or not?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios-ui-automation

My doubt is very simple.

I want to develop one big **iOS (iPhone) app of say 30 screens**.

One my friend advice me to develop whole UI in coding only and do not use XIB's or storyboard.

I want to ask that, is it feasible for me to develop whole UI in coding instead using XIB and story board?

1. Will that affect my iOS app processing?
2. Will that affect my iOS app execution speed or not?

Please suggest me the proper way weather I use XIB and Storyboard of develop UI by Coding only ..... !!!!

Thank you.

Comment: I think better to use storyboard as it will save lot of time after coding like auto layout and etc.. Also if you do everything by code then you always need update code in order to support diff. device size in future

Comment: Never code UI unless you can't implement something via Interface Builder

Comment: Yes it is correct. Thanks for your comment  @iOSWeblineindia. I have one more doubt. I heard that if I design whole UI using storyboard and so, then my application will become heavy?

Comment: Ya.. As per my knowledge and experience, Storyboard takes too much time to load or build.

Comment: Your application as bundle will not heavy. The only bad thing is when you open storyboard in Xcode it will take some time to load. But as an application it will work like normal app.

Comment: Thank you for all of your comment. UI with storyboard is best. Still one more doubt, in case of processing time which is the best option?

Comment: @NiksT, please don't post follow-up *questions* here in the comments section.  They will get hidden quickly.  If you need to request further clarification on **this** question, you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28624172/edit) the question above.  Or, post a new question.  Stack Overflow isn't a forum site, with never-ending *threads*.  After you use it for a while, you'll see why :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, tell your friend not to give you advices again.(Just kidding! :)) You can develop the whole app programmatically but it's just a pain in the gut. Apple introduced the storyboards to ease the waste of having multiple xib files in your product. 
For my personal opinion, use xibs in case of having lots of teammates working with you because of the pain of conflicts. If you're working solo, then storyboards would be the best fit.

Comment: I agree with Ashraf. I used to build everything by hand, lots of hard coded values etc... It was a a right pain.. even using xib's wasn't the easiest - The right choice now is a storyboard with constraints to handle the layout for you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no silver bullet that will solve all of your problems, every project is specific and your ability on predicting project requirements will enable you to decide. Here are some pros and cons of both approaches to help in making a decisions:

**Storyboards/XIB pros:** Very visual, Beginner friendly, Easy autolayout, MVC separation is straightforward on view side

**Storyboards/XIB cons:** SCM conflict are almost always unresolvable, not all parameters are configurable from IB so you still need to know how to do some stuff in code

**Pure Code approach pros:** Full control over entire presentation in code, conflicts resolvable easy as it can get

**Pure Code approach cons:** Might need more experience to master

My judgment would be:
Using storyboards/XIB is better solution for small to medium projects that consist of basic/stock UI elements. 
Introducing visually complex solutions and non standard transitions will require that you start writing layout code more and more and stuff becomes easier without XIBs in your way.

From my experience if you are part of the bigger dev team, Storyboards and XIBs are a big NO..

I prefer not using IB at all even for smaller projects as pressing CMD+R after writing bunch of code, and seeing it come alive is very pleasing.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally: yes, you can make an app without any storyboards or xibs. I think with iPhone 6/6+ you have to have at least one because they check it to see if you support the bigger screens, but that's it.

In fact, my first app in 2013 had almost no Xib UI design. It was iPhone portrait only, I coded with frames and was happy with the precise results I got-- I also think I learned a lot. I think with Auto Layout, especially if you learned Visual Format Language (albeit that's not a easy thing to do) creating a robust interface entirely in code is doable.

That said, not using interface builder is not doing things "the Apple way." And not doing things the Apple way is usually -- not always, but usually -- going to be more difficult. On one level, WWDC videos, guides and sample code all assume you are using IB. Creating every label, subview and view controller in code is going to take several more lines, each, than using xibs or storyboard. You will be swimming against the current.

It's worth noting IB can be immensely frustrating at times. But generally it's worth it, and you learning how to relate it to the code is learning iOS programming. Also about IB , the files it generates are just XML files, it won't have any significant effect on size or performance- I'd be wary of advice from someone who told you that.

An all-code app is doable and would be a challenging way to learn, but this is not advice I would give anyone or second.